# Simple Gmail-like solution for jQuery string filter which highlights matched text

Tags: jquery, filter, drop-down-menu

I need a simple string filter for a drop-down menu that highlights matched text.

Here's an example of such a module in use in Gmail's UI:

[image: Gmail screenshot]

I'm assuming there's a plugin for something like this, though I'm also thinking it could be simple enough to roll my own. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the jQuery UI AutoComplete widget: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: I use that already for autocompletion elsewhere, just wasn't sure it fit the right use case here.

Comment: I'm still not sure this fits my use case, and I gave an answer saying what I went with instead. While I also mentioned highlighting, I just don't care enough yet to tweak the code there, but if you have any suggestions, feel free to shoot them my way.

Comment: @Josh Smith: Don't forget to mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to tweak this code a little to get something working that's very performant and really slick: http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/javascript/how-to-build-a-fast-simple-list-filter-with-jquery/

Here's the final result already live on [Goals](http://goals.com):

[image: Screenshot]